# no visible @interface for NSMutable Array declares selector 'addStock'

Tags: objective-c

I cannot figure out why the addStock method is not working for my NSMutableArray object "giuPort" . I have properly connected all the class files. How do I make it so that the interface is visible / correct this error that comes up for each of the times I try using the addStock method?

The following snippet from my main.m file that is rendering the error is:

```
    NSMutableArray *giuPort = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [giuPort addStock:apple];
    [giuPort addStock:lvs];
    [giuPort addStock:verizon];
```

the class .h file in which I declare the NSMutableArray, etc:

```
@interface BNRPortfolio : NSObject

{
    NSMutableArray *_stocks;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *stocks;
@property (nonatomic) float valueOfPort;

//instance methods
-(void)addStock:(BNRStockHolding *)s;
-(float)valueOfPort;


@end
```

the class .m file in which I implement the NSMutableArray, etc:

```
@implementation BNRPortfolio
// array get set stuff
-(void)setStocks:(NSArray *)s
{
    _stocks = [s mutableCopy];
}

-(NSArray *)stocks
{
    return [_stocks copy];
}

// instance methods
-(void)addStock:(BNRStockHolding *)s    {
    // check to see if array exists
    if (!_stocks) {
        _stocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [_stocks addObject:s];
}

-(float)valueOfPort  {
    //take sum of all the stocks in this port
    float sum = 0;
    for (BNRStockHolding *s in _stocks) {
        sum += [s valueInDollars];

    }
    return sum;
}

@end
```

Comment: You truncated the really important bit off the title which is *which* selector is it crashing on?

Comment: Yikes, sorry: 'addStock'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-addStock:` method is a method of the `BNRPortfolio` class. You are attempting to call it on an instance of `NSMutableArray`. There's no such method on `NSMutableArray`, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

Apparently, you want to allocate and initialize an instance of `BNRPortfolio` and then call `-addStock:` on that.

Comment: ...unbelievable. To get that far and mess up on something so silly, not to mention I have been stuck on this for nearly an hour. Thank-you so much. I would up you if I could.